# Installing apache thrift and boost (C++, Java and C#)

Tags: boost, installation, thrift

So I'm thring to build an Apache Thrift application and I need running it for C++, java and C#. (Visual studio 2013 and Android Studio are the target), C++ will be server, the others will be client.

I have downloaded latest version of Apache Thrift and Boost (thrift-0.9.2 and boost_1_57_0).

Boost: I have run bootstrap.bat and then b2.exe.

After this, what I have to do for Apache thrift? I can't understand what to do now.

Comment: There is a nice [Tutorial on the website](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/). I recommend to start there.

Comment: Hey @JensG I already see this turorial, but I don't understand something: first where to use this command "./configure && make" second I need to create libthrift.lib and Thrift.dll because right now I have unresolved link. 
In my project i include both Thrift include and boost include, but now I need library, how I can create them? I need for C++, C# and Java. 
Third is not clear how to declare and set something server or client when you run the compiler (that I run with a batch)

Comment: Look under `lib/(yourTargetLanguageHere)` there are VS buiild projects for C# and C++. The `configure && make` is more or less only needed when you want to do a build on Linux.

Comment: I found them. For C# was pretty easy and I did it. For C++ is not so easy, there are two project: in both was missing boost (that i put into the folder and now is fine), but it miss also 'evhttp.h', 'event.h' in "libthriftnb project" (I have no idea what this are), and it miss 'openssl/err.h' libthrift project (here i think i must download openssl package), what are the difference between two projects?

Comment: @JensG actually I think I don't care about libthriftnb (that i think is non blocking), the libthrift work fine with openssl and I was able to run the project. Now I turn to Android Studio to make a client. Before I need to make the .jar file. I found one online, but is for java not Android, so when I call a simple function is not working, I also have added annotation.Generated and  slf4j to the library because they was missing.

Comment: Great you came this far! `evhttp.h` and `event.h` belong to `libevent`, see the [language requirements section here](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/). Re Android: "*its not working*" is generally not helpful. But it is a good opportunity to make a new, good (in SO terms) question out of it: What did you try, what happened and what did you expect? That's very likely to receive answers.

Comment: @JensG before posting this, how I can create .jar file for java? It say to use ant, but I was not able to do it. After this I will create the new question. Did you will set a reply of I reply to this question by myself?

Comment: Good question. This question already has two close votes, [because it does not meet the site's quality standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it stands. Answering would not make it much better. But you can try to completely 100% rewrite this question, instead of creating a new one. Re Ant: no idea.